# Plotting nodes with no links using igraph and R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm plotting a network as below using the igraph package, but I want to be able to show all of the nodes (Authors) in the plot, even those authors who do not have a joint paper with someone else. Is that possible?

```
PubID <- c("169759","174843","174843","174843","174843","174843","171051","171051","171051","171719","171719","171719","169759","173847","173847","177427")
Author <- c("ZJ","RA","DJ","JP","GS","Tv","MC","JR","CW","PB","MD","FO","FO","RA","DJ","KS")
dt <- data.frame(Author,PubID)
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
dt %>%
  mutate(author_id = as.integer(Author)) -> dt
dt %>%
  inner_join(dt, by = "PubID") %>%
  filter(author_id.x < author_id.y) %>%
  count(Author.x, Author.y) %>%
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE) -> g1
plot(g1)
as_data_frame(g1, what = "edges")
```

I would want to show the network, and then show the "KS" author as a single node in the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we find all those who aren't present yet:

```
(rest <- setdiff(Author, V(g1)$name))
# [1] "KS"
```

And then add them with

```
g1 <- add.vertices(g1, length(rest), attr = list(name = rest))
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! What I realise when using a bigger network is that if "KS" has more than one PubID, one which is joint with another Author and one which is unique, "KS" shows up both in the connected network and as a single node. Is there a way for KS only to appear as a single node if it is entirely unconnected?

Comment: e.g. KS would not appear as a single node in this data plot
`PubID <- c("169759","174843","174843","174843","174843","174843","171051","171051","171051","171719","171719","171719","169759","173847","173847","177427","169759")
Author <- c("ZJ","RA","DJ","JP","GS","Tv","MC","JR","CW","PB","MD","FO","FO","RA","DJ","KS","KS")`

Comment: @otter77, I can't really see happening what you said: if "KS" is already connected with someone, then "KS" will not be in `rest`, so it will not be included as an isolated node.

Comment: I think it is to do with V(g1)$name coming through as the author_id rather than the author name in my actual code. So the "rest" doesn't work as it is comparing the name with the id and hence all are being pulled through.

Comment: Fixed now though, I just had an error in one of my vertex commands. Thank you for your help!